# Tips in an Android application

Tags: android

Hey all,
I dont know if I'm not searching for it properly, but i dont seem to be able to find a "in-built" solution.

All I want to do is to display TIPS dialog in my application on how to use several of its features, similar to the one below
[Tips screen in Aldiko Ebook Reader](http://www.androidtapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/Aldiko-Book-Reader-Popup-Help-Tips-133x200.jpg)

Can anyone tell me if there is any pre defined method to do this, or Will I have to custom make this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AlertDialog is a good choice, you can customize it for your need.

Comment: Oh. I was aware of that. Just wanted to confirm if there was some kind of a inbuilt dialog for this.

Comment: Alert might not serve this need. You should use Toast message.

Answer (score 1):

First reply is, there is no API support to do this directly.

Even though you can archive it, there is some work around for that.

1. First is you can use [Toast message](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html).
2. Second way to do this is, to customize your view to show it and disappear after certain duration.

well i am in favor of Toast message as its basic Android metaphor.

Comment: I wouldn't say a `Toast` is suitable as it can only be shown for a few seconds - hardly enough time to read and digest tips for using your app. I'd suggest either an `AlertDialog` as @West_Link suggests, or perhaps a `Notification` since it will provide the necessary information but will not interfere with what the user is doing.

Comment: Ok - I have implemented a alert dialog for this purpose. But I am facing another problem. I am adding the buttons as positive/neutral and negative buttons. But what ever I do, the dialog gets dismissed after the button click is handled.

Comment: And if I add the buttons to my custom layout - I am not able to dismiss the alert dialog. I surely must be doing something wrong!

Comment: Again i would not suggest you to use Alert Dialog. Purpose of Alert dialog is different. Indirectly it is violating general guideline for Android development. Refer this, http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/seamlessness.html